# How to add arrow key as modifier key in Microsoft visual c++ project

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to move an object based on the keypressed events.i am able detect single key at a time but finding it difficult to detect two keys at same time whereas modifier keys such as ctrl,alt can be detected at same time and how is possible only for modifier keys.i just need some help to detect two arrows keys at same time,and where wil these keys values stored in visual studio.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a minimal example of what you are doing. [mcve]

Comment: I believe you are using winapi so I tagged for that. The visual c++ tag is not that descriptive because with Visual Studio you can be using many different GUI frameworks and even Android, linux or macos development which will handle this differently than windows.

Comment: What does "where wil these keys values stored in visual studio" mean?  You can use `if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000) && (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) & 0x8000))` to detect the status of two arrows keys.

Answer (score 0):

The accelerator system is not capable of this (only being able to detect a single 'normal' key along with certain modifiers).

You can use GetKeyboardState to get a table of all of the virtual keys at one time and then test or you could keep track of which keys have been pressed and which released (by handling the WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP and WM_SYSKEYDOWN/WM_SYSKEYUP messages). You could also make calls to GetAsyncKeyState, which returns the current state of single virtual keys (also state of paired virtual keys).

I would likely do this by having key-state variables, when a WM_KEYDOWN comes in I would turn that flag on then call an arrow-handling function that examines the state of all the arrow flag variables. A WM_KEYUP would only turn the flag off.